# gnu make: No rule to make target '%.c'

Tags: gnu-make

I need to use pattern rules for gnu make, but I always encounter the same error:

> make: *** No rule to make target '%.c', needed by 'test'.  Stop.

This is my Makefile:

```
all: test
test : %.c
    gcc -o $@ $?
```

The Makefile is to build an execution file from the .c files in current directory, the third line begins with a 'tab' character. I did make by:

```
make all
```

The current directory contains two c files inside:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user   43 Nov 27 11:18 test2.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  109 Nov 27 11:01 test.c
```

it always responds with the same %.c error.

I have tried:

1. Assign filenames in Makefile explicitly instead of %.c, replace the %.c with 'test.c test2.c', it works fine.
2. Create a file %.c in the current directory, and also works fine, because make can find the file of '%.c'.

My make version is:

```
$make --version
GNU Make 4.2.1
Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Copyright (C) 1988-2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

I don't know why the pattern rule function not working.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: The rule `all : %.c` is not a pattern rule, but the more important question is this: what do you want `make all` to do?

Comment: I don't think you can use pattern rules as a prereq without using them in the target. Would something like `all: $(wildcard *.c)` work for you?

Comment: I modified the Makefile to show my intentions. Hope it can help you to understand what I want to do.

Comment: It is difficult to infer intention from a script that doesn't work. I think the suggestion by @NickODell will work, as long as exactly one source file is newer than `test`.

Comment: @Beta, the script can not work is the reason I posted question on here. I just need to avoid enumeration on all .c files for compiling. Is wildcard the only way to do it? what pattern rule is invented for?

Answer (score 1):

A pattern rule is a *template* that tells make, if you want to build a target that matches this target pattern, and you can either find or build a prerequisite that matches the prerequisite pattern(s), then here's a recipe on how to do it.

A pattern rule is not a definition that says "go look for all files that match this pattern and use this rule for them".

If you want a list of source files then you can either list them by hand in your makefile, or use `$(wildcard ...)` to find them.